# Requesting Salary Outside of Advertised Range

Tags: salary, negotiation

Suppose a job applicant applies for a job that has an advertised salary range between $100K - $130K for the sake of argument. Is it, generally speaking, very difficult to negotiate a salary of $140K or $150K (or ~10% above the advertised salary upper bounds)?

Comment: Why would the company pay you more when they have three other candidates almost as good who are willing to accept a salary that fits the company's budget?

Comment: Actually, getting a salary offer that is near the top of the advertised range is quite an achievement. Unless you can show them that you can bring more value than they expected to find...

Comment: How difficult it will be is going to depend on a lot of factors you didn't include such as what you bring to the position, how difficult it is to fill, how many other qualified candidates they have and what they offer.

Answer (score 4):

The honest answer is 'It depends'.

To expand upon this, these are the factors that would influence it:

- The Companies budget. If the company only has the budget for $130K, then they only have the budget for $130K.
- The Market rate for the role. If I try to go to my local supermarket and ask for $140K for the position of Shelf Stacker, even if I'm Superman and am capable of stacking the shelves in a fraction of the time of a regular human, I'm unlikely to be able to ask for that salary.
- Your skills and experience. Suppose the company had some very specific and niche requirements where it just so happened that you ticked all of them with very substantial experience - it's possible that you could make the justification that it is worth it to the company to pay you the extra.
- Do they like you? If you really hit it off in the interview and you are aligned across all the other 'soft' factors, then it's possible that you could ask for me.

The problem you will have is if they've made the salary bracket clear in the first instance, you will likewise have to make it clear that you are seeking above this. If you go through the whole interview process and then right at the end you say 'Oh and BTW, I know the position was offering $130K, but I'm worth $150K' - that could be seen very poorly.

There are ways to have this conversation - such as "If you look at my CV, you will see that I meet or exceed all of your critical areas and a a significant number of your desirable criteria. My salary expectations are in the $140-150K range, which is a little above your range, but I believe that I can justify this based on what I bring to your company'

Comment: I disagree that you should state your salary desire up front. Partly because it is likely to exclude you from consideration before you are even interviewed, but also because you don't know the job yet. Maybe the job has incredibly satisfying work conditions, or exceptional benefits, that would make you accept $130K. If I'm asked salary expectations early on I always say "I don't know until I know more about the job".

Comment: @DJClayworth - Normally, I'd completely agree with you - but if the OP is absolutely dead-set on $140-150K, I think they should be up-front about it. I know if I went through an interview process where we had indicated our salary band and just as we were looking to give an offer the candidate turned around and said they will only accept $10-20K more than my top bracket, I'd be well annoyed.

Comment: I feel this missing the factor: Does the company have other options? Are there are other candidates that could fill the roll just as well and are happy within the salary range? Can they afford to not fill the position for another year? This is not within OPs control but it will be the key factor before any of the other points become relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it, generally speaking, very difficult to negotiate a salary ... ~10% above the advertised salary upper bounds)?

Not really. You should to bring this up fairly early in the interview process. If  it exceeds their budget or they have comparable candidates that are fine with the advertised range, this will end the process quickly. But that's what the interview process and negotiations is for: if there is no fit, it's better if you find out as early as possible. If their budget is 130k max and you need at least 150k it's a non-starter.

> Salary Negotiation **After a Job Offer**

That is more of a problem. That should have been squared away before and official offer was issued. Personally I would not issue an offer before we have at least verbal agreement on all terms and conditions including compensation. The reason for that is simple: creating a formal offer can require a lot of paperwork and an unwieldy approval process: I only want to do this once.